# How to change price for configurable products in Product Listing using drop down options in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, configurable-product, price

I have created a `custom module in magento2`, and I want to show configurable products options in the drop-down for the configurable product.

I have done using custom code, but problem is that when I change the option for a configurable product the `price does not change anything`.

Could you please let me know what we need to do to show the change price on the change that is related to the dropdown?

```
<form data-product-sku="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $product->getSku() ?>"
      action="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $block->getSubmitUrl($product) ?>" method="post"
      id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $product->getId() ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
  
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_top') ?>
    <?php if (!$block->hasOptions()):?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('product_info_form_content') ?>
    <?php else:?>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container1'):?>
            <?= $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endif; ?>

     <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <div class="product-options-wrapper" id="product-options-wrapper" data-hasrequired="* Verplichte velden">
    <?php if($product->getTypeId() === 'configurable') : ?>
        <?php foreach($product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributes($product) as $attribute) : ?>
            <div class="field configurable required">
                <label class="label" for="attribute<?php echo $attribute->getAttributeId(); ?>"><span><?php echo $attribute->getLabel() ?></span></label>
                <?php $values = $attribute->getOptions(); ?>
                <div class="control">
                    <select id="attribute<?php echo $attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" name="super_attribute[<?php echo $attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" class="super-attribute-select upsell_options" data-validate="{required:true}">
                        <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
                        <?php foreach($values as $value): ?>

                            <option value="<?php echo $value['value_index'] ?>" ><?php echo  $value['label'] ?></option>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php 
   
        ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
      </div> 
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_bottom') ?>
</form>

 <script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'priceBox'
], function($){
    var dataPriceBoxSelector = '[data-role=priceBox]',
        dataProductIdSelector = '[data-product-id=<?= $block->escapeHtml($product->getId()) ?>]',
        priceBoxes = $(dataPriceBoxSelector + dataProductIdSelector);

    priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function(index, elem){
        return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
    });

    priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to add some code to change the price while changing the drop-down, that file path is **www\app\design\frontend\XXX\XXX\Magento_Swatches\web\js**, after adding, please do setup **upgrade** and **content-deploy**

- Step-1: Add Following code in _EventListener: function () {

  ```
  $widget.element.on('change', '.' + this.options.classes.selectClass, function () {
      return $widget._OnChangeCustom($(this), $widget);
  });
  ```
- Step-2: Add this function

  ```
  _OnChangeCustom: function ($this, $widget) {
      var check = $this.val();
      var checkId = '#'+$this.parent().attr('id');
      $(checkId+' option').each(function(){
          var currentValue = $(this).val();
          if(currentValue == check){
              $(this).attr('selected', true);
              $(this).addClass('selected');
              var currentId = $(this).attr('option-id');
              $(checkId+' select').attr('option-selected',currentId);
          }else{
              $(this).removeClass('selected');
              $(this).attr('selected', false);
          }
      });
      $widget._Rebuild();

      if ($widget.element.parents($widget.options.selectorProduct)
              .find(this.options.selectorProductPrice).is(':data(mage-priceBox)')
      ) {
          $widget._UpdatePrice();
      }

      $widget._LoadProductMedia();

  },
  ```
- Step-3: Add this function

  ```
   _LoadProductMedia: function () {
      var $widget = this,
          $this = $widget.element,
          attributes = {},
          productId = 0;

      if (!$widget.options.mediaCallback) {
          return;
      }

      $this.find('[option-selected]').each(function () {
          var $selected = $(this);
          attributes[$selected.attr('attribute-code')] = $selected.attr('option-selected');
      });

      if ($('body.catalog-product-view').size() > 0) {
          //Product Page
          productId = document.getElementsByName('product')[0].value;
      } else {
          //Category View
          //create productId hidden field from list.phtml
          productId = $this.parents('.product.details.product-item-details').find('#productId').val();
      }

      var additional = $.parseParams(window.location.search.substring(1));

      $widget._XhrKiller();
      $widget._EnableProductMediaLoader($this);
      $widget.xhr = $.post(
          $widget.options.mediaCallback,
          {product_id: productId, attributes: attributes, isAjax: true, additional: additional},
          function (data) {
              var newPrice = data.special;
              var oldPrice = data.price;
              // ** add your price html here to update **
              $widget._ProductMediaCallback($this, data);
              $widget._DisableProductMediaLoader($this);
          },
          'json'
      ).done(function () {
          $widget._XhrKiller();
      });
  },
  ```